# FFPLAY shows video, but FFMPEG just shows black

Tags: ffmpeg, directshow

I'm trying to record video/audio from a VIDBOX device using *ffmpeg*.  Using Windows 10 and *ffmpeg* version N-86129-g1e8daf3, I can see and hear the video/audio fine when I execute

```
ffplay -f dshow -i video="VIDBOX NW07":audio="Microphone (VIDBOX NW07)"
```

but, I only record a black screen (and the correct audio) when I execute

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="VIDBOX NW07":audio="Microphone (VIDBOX NW07)" -c:v libx264 out.mp4
```

What could be causing this to work in *ffplay* but not *ffmpeg*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably testing the output in a generic player. Add `-pix_fmt yuv420p` to force ffmpeg's output to a standard pixel format that all players can show.

Comment: Yes.  That fixes it for me.

Comment: Yep. After lots of searches this one resolved my issue. Thank you very much